# How do I compare all elements of two arrays?

Tags: matlab, comparison, matrix, vectorization

I have two big arrays with about 1000 rows and 1000 columns. I need to compare each element of these arrays and store 1 in another array if the corresponding elements are equal.

I can do this with for loops but that takes a long time. How can I do this faster?

Comment: Always, always vectorize MATLAB code when possible.

Comment: Should be moved to http://math.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 29):

The answers given are all correct. I just wanted to elaborate on [gnovice's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202641/comparing-all-elements-of-two-arrays-in-matlab/2202651#2202651) remark about floating-point testing.

When comparing floating-point numbers for equality, it is necessary to use a tolerance value. Two types of tolerance comparisons are commonly used: absolute tolerance and relative tolerance. ([source](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22846/content/matlab_xunit/doc/html/exTolerance.html))

An absolute tolerance comparison of `a` and `b` looks like:

```
|a-b| < tol
```

A relative tolerance comparison looks like:

```
|a-b| < tol*max(|a|,|b|) + tol_floor
```

You can implement the above two as anonymous functions:

```
%# absolute tolerance equality
isequalAbs = @(x,y,tol) ( abs(x-y) <= tol );

%# relative tolerance equality
isequalRel = @(x,y,tol) ( abs(x-y) <= ( tol*max(abs(x),abs(y)) + eps) );
```

Then you can use them as:

```
%# let x and y be scalars/vectors/matrices of same size
x == y
isequalAbs(x, y, 1e-6)
isequalRel(x, y, 1e-6)
```

Comment: try: `isequal(0.3,0.1*3)` which is equivalent to `0.3 == 0.1*3`. The answer in both is false!

Comment: My apologies - I guess my faith in MATLAB was misplaced! I'm going to have to change a lot of code now :(

Comment: One point about using EPS: it is also a *relative* function. Calling EPS with no argument gives you the distance from 1.0 to the next largest double-precision number. For your second anonymous function, you would probably want to use something like `tol*eps(max(abs(x),abs(y)))`, which should give you the floating point accuracy in the range of the values in `x` and `y` (multiplied by `tol`).

Comment: also `isequal` returns a single boolean; the OP wanted a binary function that takes 2 matrices of the same size and produces a boolean matrix of that size.

Comment: @gnovice: Actually thats incorrect. if you follow the link I referenced (part of the documentation of MATLAB xUnit framework), it explains that the `tol_floor` value acts as an absolute tolerance when `a` and `b` are very close to 0. I just chose to use `eps`. As a matter of fact, you can omit it if you want and define it as: `abs(x-y) <= tol*max(abs(x),abs(y))` where the user chooses a value for `tol` (a good default value is `1e-8`)

Comment: @Amro: Ahhh, OK. I see now how you were using EPS in your equation.

Comment: @gnovice Shouldn't the tolerance depend on `eps` at the point: `abs(x-y) < max( abs( eps(x), eps(y) ) )`?

Answer (score 12):

If your two matrices `A` and `B` are the same size, then you can do this:

```
index = A == B;
```

and `index` will be a [logical array](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/logical.html) with ones everywhere an element of `A` and `B` are equal and zero otherwise.

**A word of warning...**

If `A` and `B` contain integers, the above should be fine. However, if they contain floating point values, you may get undesired results. The above code will only have values of one for elements that are *exactly* equal. Even the smallest difference will cause the elements to be considered unequal.

You can look at [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab) for more information about dealing with the "perils of floating point operations". One solution would be to check that array elements are within a given tolerance of one another, like so:

```
tolerance = 0.0001;
index = abs(A-B) <= tolerance;
```

The above will give you a logical array `index` with ones everywhere the elements of `A` and `B` are within 0.0001 of each other and zero otherwise.

Comment: Matlab has function eps, described as floating-point relative accuracy. You can use it instead of tolerance variable in gnovice's code. index = abs(A-B) <= eps;

Comment: eps is the smallest value that can be represented, isn't it? That is not very useful in this context.

Answer (score 7):

Just use the normal `==` operator:

```
>> [1 2; 3 4] == [1 5; 6 4]      

ans =

     1     0
     0     1
```