# MATLAB: comparing all elements of two arrays

Tags: matlab, matrix, comparison, vectorization

I have two matrices in MATLAB lets say `arr1` and `arr2` of size 1000*1000 each. I want to compare their elements and save the comparison in a result matrix `resarr` which is also 1000*1000 such that for each element:

- if the element in `arr1` is bigger than the one in `arr2`, place the value 1 in the result
- if the element in `arr2` is bigger, store the value 2

but I don't want to do this with for loops because that is slower. How can I do this?

---

**EDIT:**
Also if I wanted to store different RGB values in a 1000*1000*3 result matrix, depending on the comparison of `arr1` and `arr2`, could that be done without slow loops?

For example store (255,0,0) if `arr1` is larger and (0,255,0) if `arr2` is larger

Comment: This is a VERY similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202641/how-do-i-compare-all-elements-of-two-arrays-in-matlab

Comment: @Doresoom: Agreed. *Very* similar, but *technically* different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
resarr = 2 - (arr1 > arr2)
```

`arr1>arr2` compares arr1 and arr2, element by element, returning 1000x1000 matrix containing 1 where arr1 is larger, and 0 otherwise. the `2 -`  part makes it into a matrix where there are 1's if arr1 was larger than arr2, and 2's otherwise.

note: if arr1 and arr2 are euqal at some point, you'll also get 2 (because arr1>arr2 return 0, then 2-0=2).

Comment: can you tell me what I would do if I wanted to assign different RGB value to a 1000*1000*3 result array, depending on the comparison results of arr1 and arr2??

Comment: As a remark, even though this code is correct, performance-wise note that by storing 1/2 instead of true/false you are creating a matrix x8 times the size of the logical type..

Answer (score 2):

With respect to your edit, once you have your `resarr` matrix computed as [Ofri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209194/matlab-comparing-all-elements-of-two-arrays/2209212#2209212) suggested, you can modify an RGB matrix `img` in the following way:

```
N = numel(resarr);  %# The number of image pixels

index = find(resarr == 1);  %# The indices where arr1 is bigger
img(index) = 255;           %# Change the red values
img(index+N) = 0;           %# Change the green values
img(index+2*N) = 0;         %# Change the blue values

index = find(resarr == 2);  %# The indices where arr2 is bigger
img(index) = 0;             %# Change the red values
img(index+N) = 255;         %# Change the green values
img(index+2*N) = 0;         %# Change the blue values
```