# How to compare two vectors element by element?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two matrices: `A=[1,2,3,4,5]` and `B=[1,2,3,4,6]`. I need to compare elements of those matrix, and as a result I need to have binary matrix 
`Result=[1,1,1,1,0]`, that means if `A(i)==B(i)` then `Result(i)=1` else  `Result(i)=0`.

I have tried with:

```
if (isequal (A,B))
   Result=1
else
   Result=0
end
```

I have tried: `Result=sign(A,B)`

I hope that you could help me please?

Comment: Did you try `A == B`?

Comment: it  gives me Result= 0, however i need the result is a matrix.

Comment: Are you sure it gives you `Result = 0`?

Comment: yes I am sure, @StewieGriffin, it isn't a duplicate question.

Comment: How is this not a duplicate? They are identical as far as I can see, only that the other one applies to two dimensions instead of one. Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2202651/2338750) not solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5]
B = [1,2,3,4,6]
Result = A == B
```

Comment: I thought you said `A == B` didn't work?

Comment: A==B, just gives me Result = 0, but Result= A==B gives  me the best  Result=[0,0,0,0,1]

Comment: `A == B`; `ans = [1     1     1     1     0]`